# How to map over external JSON data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have save JSON data as `profiledata.js` file. I want to map through each object and display it on page. I know that `.map()` function only works on `array` and not `objects`. So I created array of objects but still could not display the data on page using `.map()`.

profiledata.js:

```
const profiledata = [  {
        "_id": {
          "_str": "5b0761dc88430400064d9a31"
        },
        "batting": {
          "_id": {
            "_str": "54cc1859ce17393ab3219eda"
          },
          "avgRate": 43,
          "centuries": 0,
          "halfCenturies": 0,
          "highestScore": 43,
          "notOut": 0,
          "numInnings": 1,
          "numMatches": 1,
          "strikeRate": null,
          "teamid": {
            "_str": "54cc196cce17393ab321a9e6"
          },
          "totalBalls": 18,
          "totalFours": 2,
          "totalPoints": 78,
          "totalRuns": 43,
          "totalSixes": 5
        },
        "bowling": {
          "_id": {
            "_str": "54cc1859ce17393ab3219eda"
          },
          "bestInnings": {
            "runs": 39,
            "wickets": 0
          },
          "numMatches": 1,
          "runRate": 6.5,
          "totalBalls": 0,
          "totalMaidens": 0,
          "totalNoBalls": 1,
          "totalOvers": 6,
          "totalPoints": 5,
          "totalRuns": 39,
          "totalWickets": 0,
          "totalWides": 0
        },
        "division": "A",
        "fielding": [],
        "matches": 1,
        "player": {
          "_str": "54cc1859ce17393ab3219eda"
        },
        "points": 83,
        "season": "2018",
        "team": {
          "_str": "54cc196cce17393ab321a9e6"
        },
        "tournament": {
          "_str": "f4e8a58fd0d90574856d1a46"
        },
        "tournamentString": "f4e8a58fd0d90574856d1a46"
      },
    {},
    {},
    ....
    ];

    export default profiledata;
```

chart.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import profiledata from './profiledata';


class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          {profiledata.map( newdata => {
            return(
              <div>
            <li> {newdata._id}</li>
              </div>
            );
          })}

      </div>
    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

I am trying to display `_id` of each object using `.map()`. I am importing `profiledata` into my component called `chart.js`. Check screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you used webpack

Comment: @ShubhamBatra I have used `create-react-app`

Comment: @ShubhamBatra No such file exists.

Comment: Try console to print `profiledata`. Are you getting data as expected in render function.

Comment: @KishanMundha Non I am getting empty object.

Comment: It mean issue with data. I'm not sure what exact issue, but might be we are importing wrong file or empty file or something wrong in `profiledata`

Comment: profiledata is not component . add `.js` after it. `import profiledata from './profiledata.js';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add .js while inporting profile Data.
replace this line

```
import profiledata from './profiledata';
```

to

```
import profiledata from './profiledata.js';
```

Comment: When I don't import profiledata i.e combine chart.js and profiledata.js it console.log the data so I think problem is with importing.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with importing. does above solution work for you?

Comment: No you don't need to add `.js` as I am exporting it. I have figured out the solution. Just deleted the file and created a new json file and then imported.

Comment: @stonerock glad you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling newdata._id when ._id is an object containing '_str', which is what you want.

Try,

```
newdata._id._str
```